# A way to divide up an array into smaller sub arrays such that the time to process all sub arrays is equal

Tags: optimization, multiprocessing, combinations

I am trying to efficiently do multiprocessing and have X items that will be divided into Y cpu_cores. In order to do this I take the X items and split them up into Y lists and feed those into the program. The problem is that certain items take longer than others and I end up with Y-1 Cores finishing and waiting on the Y-th core for a long time. I already have the run-times of each of these X-items. How can I efficiently calculate subarrays such that the time to process all of them would be approximately equal?

I tried doing a combination of all possible subarrays and finding those most equal in time, but this approach takes too long especially as the input grows to over 100 2^100 operations is infeasible. Any ideas for a heuristic that will give me "good" subarrays those that have approximately similar runtimes?

Comment: Well, you'll always face this situation if you inflexibly divide the work up. Say 1 task in your 10000 items takes an hour, while the rest take a second: You're going to end up with a single thread taking some time. In this case, it may be best to have the remaining work available for every thread, allowing them to pull/remove tasks (or chunks of tasks) when they're ready for more.

Comment: I forgot to mention the amount of tasks is static along with the amount of cores, that is why I am trying to find the global optimum ahead of time instead of just creating a scheduler like you mentioned.

Comment: A multiple knapsack problem with a balance constraint, or maybe a partition problem? Either way, definitely not a programming problem. You might want to ask in [cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). Although I would suggest sorting in descending order of processing time and then passing it to the thread pool.

Comment: The other comments are on point.  In general, you should *not* need to do this.  A multi-processing pool will work everything in parallel until all are done and feed each thread from the stack of tasks.  If you wanted to get cute, you could feed in the largest tasks first if you know what they are.  If python, this is a good ref:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html  Other languages have similar capabilities